# Find the region at which the curve transitions from linear growth to exponential growth

Tags: geometry

I have a set of $2D$ points: let's say $x$ and $y$. I start from $x = 0$ and increment by $1$ and for each increment I record the value of $y$. So, $y$ is a function in $x$.
If i plot the graph of $x$ v/s $y$, initially $y$ increases linearly with $x$ and at some point starts increasing exponentially. The curve is smooth.
Now, I need to find the region at which the curve transitions from linear growth to exponential growth. I need an algorithm to do find that region so as to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically if

> initially y increases **linearly** with x

then you may just check the first point which is not aligned with the two firsts.

If it is too strict then you could measure the distance of the y coordinates between two consecutive points. And you can then put some criteria. This depends mostly on the properties of your datas (scale, step size, etc...).

For $k=0,1,\ldots$ running in your ordered set of points consider

$s_k = \dfrac{|y_{k+1}-y_{k}|}{|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|}% \iff \beta=\dfrac{\ln(c)}{\ln(|x_{k+1}-y_{k}|)-\ln(|y_{k}-y_{k-1}|)}$, and $ \alpha_k = \dfrac{\ln(s_k)}{\ln(s_{k+1})}$ $(\iff s_k = s_{k+1}^{\alpha_{k}})$

For $\alpha_k = 1$ you have approximative linear growing between $(x_k,y_k)$ and $(x_{k+1},y_{k+1}))$. If $\alpha_k > 1$ then the growing is exponential. Make a plot of the $\alpha_k$, could be interesting :).

Comment: point are not exactly linear but when we increase the value of x then at a point value of y increasing very high. I would like to find that point,

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sir if the graph is initially constant, then increase linearly and then increase exponentially

Comment: This shows that it is first growing linearly (where the graph of $\alpha_k$ is constant) and then it it start to be exponential (where the graph linearly increase) and finally the exponent itself increases (i.e. the growing becomes even bigger than exponential). Just find the first $k$ such that $|\alpha_k-\alpha_{k+1}|<\epsilon$ for some tolerance $\epsilon$ depending on how "approximatively constant" is the graph of the $\alpha_k$. Note also that exponent associated to the exponentially growing part of the graph of $(x,y)$ is given by the slope of the linear part of the graph for $\alpha_k$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting problem and I give you the manner I solved it quite many times.

Let us suppose that you have your data points ($x_i,y_i$) ($i=1$ to $N$) sorted by increasing $x$. For $1 \le i \le k$ you use model $A$ and for $k+1 \le i \le N$ you use model $B$. So, you can compute for each value of $k$ a discrete function $$F(k)=SSQ_A+SSQ_B$$ ($SSQ$ standing for sum of squares). So, running basically from $k=2$, you will see where $F(k)$ is minimum; for this value of $k_{opt}$, keep the value of the parameters of model $A$ and model $B$.

This is the preliminary step of the procedure. If you want you can continue and polish the solution introducing an extra parameter (say $x_*$) and you global model will be :

- if $x_i \lt x_*$, then $y$ is computed according to model A
- if $x_i \gt x_*$, then $y$ is computed according to model B

This works as a standard nonlinear regression (remember that you have good guesses of the parameters from the first step).

I should be very happy to hear how it is good for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sir if the graph is initially constant, then increase linearly and then increase exponentially.

Comment: I have been very happy to provide this solution method I set ... $50$ years ago ! Please let me know how it works for you. Cheers :)

Comment: It is sure that you make the problem more complex but the same approach could be used. Your $F(k_1,k_2)$ is now a surface but it does not matter. Moreover, I suppose that plotting your data would give you a good idea of the starting points for the $3D$ search. Could you put somewhere some data in order I play with them ?